# jQuery $.get() isn't working anywhere I try. jsFiddle Included

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I am trying to grab a webpage using the $.get() jQuery function, and so far have been unsuccessful.

I have the following function:

```
$.get("http://www.lavancier.com/brockCharts/actual-data.html", function(response) { 
document.write(response);
});
```

That has a valid URL and inside that url is a json (just on a plain html page however). When I try to write the contents, nothing happens. Anyone know why?

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/brockwhittaker/pxq2kkkf/

Comment: Any errors in the console? Are you sure you have included jQuery? Are you running this from the same domain (www.lavancier.com) ? How come your HTML page is actually a JSON?

Comment: Yes, I was. Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/brockwhittaker/pxq2kkkf/

Comment: I figured it out. It was a no-access issue. By getting rid of the http://www...... part, I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a server config. The server is denying ajax request outside its origin.

It will work if the server has header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` set. Or, if you move your script to the same origin.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the console (I am using chrome) I can see that you are getting the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.lavancier.com/brockCharts/actual-data.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

You need to add a header to lavancier.com which allows cross domain. See [Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)